# Error in running Angular 6 from nodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

My project structure is

```
myApp-
     |-dist -
             |- myApp -
                      |- index.html
                      |- main.js

     |-server- 
             |- app.js

     |-src-
             | - app
             | - assets
             | - index.html
             | - main.ts
```

my `app.js` file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));


app.get('/',(req,res)=> {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/myApp/index.html'));
});

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, ()=>{
  console.log('Server running at port ', port)
});
```

*And Angular file is same as default*

But it shows just an empty page. 
I know it is reaching to `index.html` because it changes the name of the title as in index.html but it is not reaching to `app.component.html`

index.html page is

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>BtechApp</title>
      <base href="/BtechApp">

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and when I am inspecting that page it shows error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Also, I checked on net as path of index.html from app.js is

```
dist -
     | - index.html
```

But in my Case path is

```
dist -
     | - myApp -
               | - index.html
```

**NOTE** - I found the problem was in my app.js file, You can check my answer below.

Comment: Where's the angular code? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @Clint on inspecting page it shows `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
`

Comment: Sounds like a syntax error with your javascript. With what's in the question there is little we can do to help.

Comment: Generally, in angular-cli anyway, the dist folder is where the code compiled from the src folder is placed. Your index.html file has a distinct lack of `script` elements in it, leading me to believe something has gone wrong in the compile process.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I use `ng build` command to compile.

Comment: Please provide more information about your setup and how you are running your code. Right now it is night on impossible to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @HereticMonkey please check I have updated my query.

Comment: From what you've shown, you have nothing in your src folder. That is unlikely to product anything very interesting after running ng build...

Comment: @HereticMonkey  src folder contains all default folder which is obtained by installing angular.

Answer (score 0):

index.html has  tag instead of the type of the document. So when node is trying to parse your index.html, it gets the first character as < and that is what it is complaining about. Putting html tag should help.

Comment: where should I put that tag?

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
Dont forget to close the html tag at the end of your document

Comment: I am closing every tag in the index.html. You can see above.

Answer (score 0):

I was only giving the wrong path to index.html

so the new app.js will be as

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/newApp'));

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname));
});
```